# json_encode "съедает" символ \

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

Доброго времени! такая проблема создал аякс запрос который генерирует html код и возвращает его в файле обработчике это выглядит так

```
 $res['par1'] = "<span id='valsbc".$getupst['id']."'>".$vals."</span>\10";
 echo json_encode($res);
```

далее когда js принимает ответ вставляет в нужное место это так

```
var stbar = html.par1;
$("#allststusbuton").html(stbar);
```

и проблема в том что наверно джейсон съедает символ \ и десятку после него потому что именно они не отображаются, а вместо них символ низвестного элемента (квадратик с маленькими ноликами и восьмеркой)

Comment: приведи пример строк

Comment: <td><span id='valsbc".$getupst['id']."'>".$vals."</span>/\10</td>   это из обработчика на выводи становится таким [https://hkar.ru/O0OV](https://hkar.ru/O0OV)

Comment: используй кавычки наоборот, т.е. всё возьми в одинарные, внутри идентификатор уже будет в двойных `'<span id="valsbc'.$getupst['id'].'">'.$vals.'</span>\10';`............. либо экранируй обратный слеш `"<span id='valsbc".$getupst['id']."'>".$vals."</span>\\10";`

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Экрпнировение \\ помогло - списибо) если конвертируете комментарий в ответ то я закрою вопрос

Comment: Ты и сам можешь написать ответ. Просто, кмк, нужно написать причину такого поведения, раскрыть тему, так сказать. А мне лень))